# Circle not showing up in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I'm trying to draw circles inside of the `inner` panel. I have a class, `paintTimeUnit` that creates the circle inside the panel given an xy coordinate pair but whenever I create a new `paintTimeUnit` object and add it to the panel it doesn't seem to be showing up.

```
public class paintTimeUnit extends JPanel {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int value;
    private int xlocation;
    private int ylocation;

    public paintTimeUnit(int x, int y) {
        value = 0;
        xlocation = x;
        ylocation = y;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {    
        g.drawOval(xlocation, ylocation, 100, 100);  
        g.setColor(Color.RED);    
    }  

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int t) {
        value = t;
    }

}
```

And the implementation of it is as follows:

```
           JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
           ...
           JPanel inner = new JPanel();
           inner.setLayout(null);
           inner.setSize(325, 570);
           inner.setBackground(null);
           inner.setLocation(500, 350);
           inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
           inner.setVisible(true);

           paintTimeUnit hour1 = new paintTimeUnit(600, 400);
           hour1.setValue(1);
           hour1.setVisible(true);
           inner.add(hour1);

           //----Containers to Panel/Panel to Frame---------
           Panel.add(inner);
           ...
           frame.add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Some comments on your code: 
1. I think it's better to use "setPreferredSize" to set the dimensions
2. why do you set the color, after you draw the circle?

Comment: @souls Thanks for the feedback! I don’t have a lot of experience with swing/awt so to me it just seems logical to set the Color after creating the circle.

Comment: It has been a long time since I was working with awt, but try to flip it. Another question: does it have to be awt? I recommend using JavaFX, if you have the opportunity.

Comment: @souls I’ll try switching them after i get off work to see if that does anything. I can use FX. That’s a good idea since I have a bit more experience with it then I do with awt

Comment: *it just seems logical to set the Color after creating the circle.* - how is that logical? How would you expect the circle to be painted red if you change the color AFTER the circle is drawn?  @solus *I think it's better to use "setPreferredSize" to set the dimensions* - no you should not use setPreferredSize(). Instead you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the custom component.

Comment: You should not be creating a unique component for each circle. Instead you have a single component that does custom painting. Then you keep an ArrayList of objects to paint. The paintComponent() method then just iterates through the ArrayList to paint each object. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach.

Comment: @camickr I think you’re forgetting the part about me not having a lot of experience with swing or using awt . Regardless of that, thanks for the helpful tip.

Comment: Looking through the link it’ll be very useful in redoing my code and to learn more about painting

Comment: *I think you’re forgetting the part about me not having a lot of experience* - which is why I indicated you were using a wrong approach, so you can rethink what you are doing.  I provided you with the link that contains links to other painting resources as well as example code. You learn by reading, not having others write the code for you.

Comment: @camickr my goal isnt to have someone write my code for me. I'm just trying to learn given my inexperience. This isn't a school assignment, there's no deadline, no grade. That link was helpful truly as well as your previous comment. Its really something small in the grand scheme of things, getting heated or making sly comments about me wanting you to write my code for me. Weather i was reading that first comment with the right tone or not it just seemed to be slightly over the top considering in my mind i thought "how am i supposed to know that when I've barely ever worked with swing/awt?"

Comment: @camickr which resulted in my comment that had the goal of conveying you were overly critical of me, not that you should write my code for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a component that draws a circle at a given location, properly override `paintComponent` as explained in oracle's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html):

```
class PaintTimeUnit extends JPanel {

    private final int xlocation, ylocation;
    private static final int W = 500, H = 300, RADIUS = 50;

    public PaintTimeUnit(int x, int y) {
        xlocation = x;
        ylocation = y;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W, H));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //override paintComponent for custom painting
        super.paintComponent(g); //call super
        g.setColor(Color.RED);  //set painting color
        g.drawOval(xlocation, ylocation, RADIUS, RADIUS); //draw circle
    }
}
```

However, as advised, it may better to have a container that draws a bunch of circles. 
To achieve it you need to add a collection to store all circles to be painted such as

`List<Point> circleCenters== new ArrayList<>()`

You would also need to add points to that collection:

```
 void addCircle(int centerX, int centerY){
    circleCenters.add(new Point(centerX, centerY));
 }
```

and have `paintComponent` draw circles based on their stored centers:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //override paintComponent for custom painting
    super.paintComponent(g); //call super
    g.setColor(Color.RED);  //set painting color
    for(Point center : circleCenters){
       g.drawOval(center.x, center.y, RADIUS, RADIUS); //draw circle
    }
}
```

Put it all together:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class PaintTimeUnit extends JPanel {

    private final List<Point> circleCenters;
    private static final int W = 500, H = 300, RADIUS = 50;

    public PaintTimeUnit() {
        circleCenters = new ArrayList<>();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W, H));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //override paintComponent for custom painting
        super.paintComponent(g); //call super
        g.setColor(Color.RED);  //set painting color
        for(Point center : circleCenters){
            g.drawOval(center.x, center.y, RADIUS, RADIUS); //draw circle
        }
    }

    void addCircle(int centerX, int centerY){
        circleCenters.add(new Point(centerX, centerY));
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
 PaintTimeUnit ptu= new PaintTimeUnit();
 //add 3 circles
 ptu.addCircle(90,90);
 ptu.addCircle(150,150);
 ptu.addCircle(210,90);
```

---

([Run it online](https://repl.it/repls/ExtrovertedYawningSequence))