# Not sure if I am overriding paintComponent() correctly

Tags: java, swing, awt

For someone who is wanting to learn more about awt/swing and who has not worked a lot with awt/swing I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly or not. What I am trying to do is override paintComponent() with a method that creates 6 circles that are supposed to be added to the `inner` panel in certain spots (the `x + 50` and `y + 50` are just for testing purposes). I've looked through online resources including this site and the circles still don't appear to be showing up. I'm sure I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what. Tips and/or informative links would be greatly appreciated

This is the class I have with the goal of creating and adding the circles to the panel:

```
public class TimeUnit extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int x = -50;
private int y = -50;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    ArrayList<Graphics> list = new ArrayList<Graphics>(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        list.add(g.create());
    }

    for (Graphics r : list) {
        r.drawOval(x + 50, y + 50, 50, 50);

    }

}
```

And this is where it is incorporated into my main program:

```
           JPanel inner = new JPanel();
           inner.setLayout(null);
           inner.setSize(325, 570);
           inner.setBackground(null);
           inner.setLocation(500, 350);
           inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
           inner.setVisible(true);
           inner.repaint();



           //----Containers to Panel/Panel to Frame---------
           Panel.add(inner);
           Panel.add(labelOne);
           Panel.add(labelTwo);
           Panel.add(labelFour);
           Panel.add(labelEight);
           Panel.add(timeLabel);
           frame.add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: `paintComponent` should only paint, It should not change the object it is painting. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437287/3992939)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the passed in `Graphics g` to draw the ovals, not create new `Graphics` objects:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawOval(x + 50*i, y + 50*i, 50, 50);
    }
}
```